Laravel 11 Reverb and React Websocket connection error
I am trying to build a real-time chat application, but I am encountering issues connecting to my Reverb server from React. The error message I receive is as follows: runtime.ts:115 WebSocket connection to 'wss://localhost:8080/app/knycnmdeg1hemq2vnt1i?protocol=7&client=js&version=8.4.0-rc2&flash=false' failed: .
Could you help me troubleshoot this problem?
Here is my .env
REVERB_APP_ID=147846
REVERB_APP_KEY=knycnmdeg1hemq2vnt1i
REVERB_APP_SECRET=xccoqs0txoecjmjw8ol5
REVERB_HOST="localhost"
REVERB_PORT=8080
REVERB_SCHEME=http

VITE_REVERB_APP_KEY="${REVERB_APP_KEY}"
VITE_REVERB_HOST="${REVERB_HOST}"
VITE_REVERB_PORT="${REVERB_PORT}"
VITE_REVERB_SCHEME="${REVERB_SCHEME}"

BROADCAST_CONNECTION=reverb



Here is my broadcasting.php
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Broadcaster
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default broadcaster that will be used by the
    | framework when an event needs to be broadcast. You may set this to
    | any of the connections defined in the "connections" array below.
    |
    | Supported: "reverb", "pusher", "ably", "redis", "log", "null"
    |
    */

    'default' => env('BROADCAST_CONNECTION', 'null'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Broadcast Connections
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may define all of the broadcast connections that will be used
    | to broadcast events to other systems or over WebSockets. Samples of
    | each available type of connection are provided inside this array.
    |
    */

    'connections' => [

        'reverb' => [
            'driver' => 'reverb',
            'key' => env('REVERB_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('REVERB_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('REVERB_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'host' => env('REVERB_HOST'),
                'port' => env('REVERB_PORT', 443),
                'scheme' => env('REVERB_SCHEME', 'https'),
                'useTLS' => env('REVERB_SCHEME', 'https') === 'https',
            ],
            'client_options' => [
                // Guzzle client options: https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html
            ],
        ],

        'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
                'host' => env('PUSHER_HOST') ?: 'api-'.env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER', 'mt1').'.pusher.com',
                'port' => env('PUSHER_PORT', 6001),
                'scheme' => env('PUSHER_SCHEME', 'https'),
                'encrypted' => true,
                'useTLS' => env('PUSHER_SCHEME', 'https') === 'https',
            ],
            'client_options' => [
                // Guzzle client options: https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html
            ],
        ],

        'ably' => [
            'driver' => 'ably',
            'key' => env('ABLY_KEY'),
        ],

        'log' => [
            'driver' => 'log',
        ],

        'null' => [
            'driver' => 'null',
        ],

    ],

];


Here is my echo.ts
import Echo from "laravel-echo";
import Pusher from "pusher-js";
//@ts-ignore
window.Pusher = Pusher;

const echo  = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'reverb',
    key: "knycnmdeg1hemq2vnt1i",
    wsHost: "localhost",
    wsPort: 8080,
    wssPort: 8080,
    forceTLS: 'http',
    enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss'],
});

export default echo;

I was trying to install various packages, but none of them worked for me. Can you help me troubleshoot this issue?

Did you get solution for this? I have the same issue.
ws://localhost:8080 complains that this is not reachable

Did you run or start php artisan reverb:start in your terminal?

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
